# iterm2 split pane - type simultaneously in both split windows

Tags: terminal, iterm

I am using `iterm2`. I would like to issue a command in one of the `split pane` windows and get that executed in the other `split pane window` session as well. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`iterm2` has a feature which does exactly the same. Click `Shell`->`Broadcast Input`->`Broadcast input to All panes in current tab`.

Comment: Shortcut for this is:  ⌘⌥I  (Cmd + Opt + letter I)